# iterate in variadic templates without parameters

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I have a data object "value" which can contain different types of values (int, std::string, bool etc).
I want to deserialize it in a tuple using variadic template :

```
tuple<int, std::string, bool> tuple = data.Deserialize<int, std::string, bool>();
```

In my Deserialize method I want to iterate over types (here int, std::string and bool) to call each time another Deserialize method who knows how to get data.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, via either pack expansion or recursion. What did you try, and how did it fail?

Comment: I'm new to this and I don't know what to try. I've done successfuly the Serialization part, by 'calling' my method with the "T... arg" parameter, but I don't understand it very well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible ?

Yes.

---

Here's a C++17 solution:

```
template <typename T>
struct type_wrapper { using type = T; };

template <typename... Ts, typename TF>
void for_types(TF&& f)
{
    (f(type_wrapper<Ts>{}), ...);
}
```

Usage:

```
for_types<int, std::string, bool>([](auto t)
{
    using t_type = typename decltype(t)::type;
    // logic for type `t_type` ...
});
```

[**live wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/0vSUuRrTEEGlEM1L)

---

And here's a C++11 solution:

```
template <typename TF, typename... Ts>
void for_each_arg(TF&& f, Ts&&... xs)
{
    using swallow = int[];
    return (void)swallow{(f(std::forward<Ts>(xs)), 0)...};
}

template <typename T>
struct type_wrapper { using type = T; };

template <typename... Ts, typename TF>
void for_types(TF&& f)
{
    for_each_arg(std::forward<TF>(f), type_wrapper<Ts>{}...);
}
```

Usage:

```
struct body
{
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(type_wrapper<T>) const
    {
        // logic for type `T` ...
    }
};

int main()
{
    for_types<int, float, bool>(body{});
}
```

[**live wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/BuXEto1MmkDPvnKs)

---

You can apply the techniques presented inside `for_types` directly in your `Deserialize` definition if you don't need a general way of iterating over a sequence of types.

Comment: Pardon me, but why the double serving of generic lambdas rather than `(void)(something<Ts>(), ...);` directly inside `Deserialize`?

Comment: @Quentin: I'm just trying to show a generic way of iterating over types - the *fold expression* and `for_each_arg` solutions can be directly used in the body of `Deserialize`. I'll make that clearer in my answer.

Comment: Caution: `(int[]){0}` is not syntactically valid. You need a typedef (`intArr{0}`) or a wrapper (`typename identity<int[]>::type`).

Comment: @Quentin: it compiles with both g++4.7 and clang++3.2 *(and newer)*. Investigating...

Comment: In C, that would be a compound literal. I suspect they're available in C++ via an extension.

Comment: @Quentin: makes sense - I changed it to use a *type alias* instead.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo, tanks it works, but I don't understand this part : "return (void)swallow{(f(std::forward<Ts>(xs)), 0)...};" how does it work ?

Comment: @Morgan: it's commonly known as the `for_each_argument` snippet by Sean Parent. I made a 30 minutes talk about it at CppCon 2015: [**“`for_each_argument` explained and expanded"**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2l83JlqkzBk)